# Admin UI anomalies when using Chrome browser

Tags: magento-1.8, admin

I've used Chrome for years but recently I'm experiencing anomalies that prevent me from using it (or Firefox), I can only effectively administer through IE.

A few examples of the problems in Chrome and Firefox...

- The Manage Products list doesn't show the mouse-over highlighting as
  I scroll-over the list of products
- I cannot click on a row in the list to edit a product, I can only open the product by clicking on the edit link
- when I edit a product the details are not shown, when I click on a 'tab' on the left, it doesn't display the form on the right
- I see the same behavior for other lists (Customer, Orders, etc.)

Again, Internet Explorer (11.0.28) works fine, but both Chrome (49.0.2623.87) and FireFox(38.6.1) exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some extensions added to both Chrome and Firefox?
Admin panel use Javascript code to run. Pleas open Console where problem occur (CTRL+SHIFT+I in Chrome) and go to tab Console. There can be some extension that break js and in console there is error. Write all of them there.

Comment: I think you may be correct about extensions.  When I run in 'incognito' mode within chrome I don't see the issues.  I guess I'll disable all extensions and enable one at a time to see what is interfering.

Comment: This is strange... I disabled all my extensions,  Magento Admin pages worked correctly.  I re-enabled them one at a time and found when they were all enabled again, Magento Admin pages still worked correctly.   I guess I can be happy it works now, but not satisfying not knowing why!

Comment: When enabling extension you must restart Chrome. If you write down list of extension then i can check it or others. There is solution even, if re-enabling extension didn't help but you **lose all data**!!!. 

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214